# Algorithms - Calculating Sums, variance, and efficieny

Tags: algorithm

I am in a class for Computer algorithms, I'm having trouble and the teacher is trying to help me. I am doing some problems in the book, but I just can't wrap my head around them.

I know how to do the notation that wolphra-alpha uses for these.
So for instance I have this: "Computer the following sum:   Sum_(i=1)^n    for 1/i(i+1)"
I am completely bewildered as to what I have to do to calculate such sum, I've had it explained to me a few times already, so the most detailed and coherent explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Another problem asks to Find and Compare the # of divisions/multiplications/additions and subtractions that are required for computing variance for the following formulas:

Formula 1:  (Sum_(i=1)^n  for  (x-y)^2)/(n-1)   where y =  (Sum_(i=1)^n for x)/n

Formula 2: ((Sum_(i=1)^n  for  x^2)  -  ((Sum_(i=1)^n for x)/n))  / (n-1)

I am still lost entirely as to what I need to do.

I appreciate any and all help, even links to good material to read. I've read my textbook and quite a bit online.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math algorithms and not programming.

Comment: It's a computational algorithm class that is why I put it in here for that. I was going to add an actual code example but I think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

For `Sum_(i=1)^n for 1/i(i+1)`, the underscore `_` is what goes under the ∑ symbol, and `^` is for what goes above it. In other words,

```
     n
     ∑  1/(i(i+1))
    i=1
```

I'm assuming you mean i(i+1) to be in the denominator. This sum is equal to

```
1/(1(1+1)) + 1/(2(2+1)) + 1/(3(3+1)) + ... + 1/(n(n+1))
```

Make sure you can see the pattern here. Notice that this *only* depends on `n`, and not anything else (like `i`).

In C/C++, this would look like

```
double f(int n)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for( int i=1 ; i<=n ; ++i ) sum += 1.0/(i*(i+1));
    return sum;
}
```

Hope that helps.